# c# - How to get specific values out of a DataTable using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

I have an Access table which looks like this:

```
ID | col_1 | col_2 | col_n
1  | 12345 | ...   | ...
1  | null  | ...   | ... 
1  | null  | ...   | ...
2  | 67891 | ...   | ...
```

What I want to accomplish is to get all `col_1` with the ID `1` if there is at least one value in `col_1` with that ID. So my result would be:

```
ID | col_1 
1  | 12345
1  | null
1  | null
```

The following code gets me the all the values of `ID` and `col_1` and stores them in a `DataTable results0`.

```
 public void ConnectDB(string path, string query0, string query1)
    {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + path + ";Persist Security Info=False";

        try
        {
            using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
            {
                DataTable results0 = new DataTable();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query0, conn);

                conn.Open();

                OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);

                adapter.Fill(results0); 

            }

        }


        catch (System.InvalidOperationException inv)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(inv.Message);


            throw;
        }
}
```

I wanted to use LINQ for this issue, since I don't want to loop through the rows and tried a few things without success. At first I thought something like this would give me the relevant values (which it does)

```
  int id = 1; 
        for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) // iterate through IDs and increment
        {
             IEnumerable<String> Ids = 
                 results0
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Where(row => row.Field<Int32>("ID") == id)
                .Select(row => row.Field<String>("FERI"));

             id+=1;
        }
```

but I'm not sure how to rephrase it in an if-statement. Something like "If ID = 1 and at least one value in col_1 get range of rows with ID = 1"

I hope this isn't too confusing. 
Any help and suggestions are appreciated!

**Update:** I'm still having trouble getting the relevant rows. I tried using `DataRow[]`, selecting all the rows with ID = 1 and iterating with foreach-loops but this doesn't seem really efficient. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

To get the list of records with ID==1 from the Database assuming database with name "DBName", we will have:

```
public DBName _dbContext = new DBName ();
```

and then using following LINQ query we will get result:

```
_dbContext.TableName.Where(u => u.ID  == 1).Select(u => u.col_1 ).ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I can follow. Where do I need to declare DBName?

Comment: @Allix In you controller under declaration section, do declare this line "public yourDataBaseName _anyVariableName = new yourDataBaseName (); " and then use LINQ Query given above to select data. Will work for sure!

Comment: I didn't downvote either of your suggestions. And thanks, I'll try that!

Comment: I added my Access-DB as DataSet to my project and followed your instructions. It seems to be working but it only returns the column names and not the actual rows/values. At least this is what I'm seeing while debugging. I'm not sure if I did this right. Any ideas?

Comment: Select statement is selecting only first column name, if you require more data do add it in select here

Comment: and if you don't write select here then it will get full tuple.

Answer (score 0):

Real easy.

```
           DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns.Add("col_1", typeof(int));
            dt.Columns["col_1"].AllowDBNull = true;

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, 12345});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, null});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, null});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, 67891});

            int id = 1;
            DataTable dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(x => x.Field<int>("ID") == id).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Since I would need to add >700 rows manually this is not the right approach.